# com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException backendless generated code

Tags: android-studio, backendless

I download the generated code from the development console for my backendless app. I am able to build the project, but I get the following error message run I try to run the project.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':Eye-CRUD:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK weborb.tasks    File1:
>   C:\Users\msih\Downloads\backendless-codegen-nologin\backendless-codegen\Eye-Codegen\libs\backendless.jar
>     File2:
>   C:\Users\msih\Downloads\backendless-codegen-nologin\backendless-codegen\Eye-Codegen\Eye-CRUD\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Eye-Codegen\Eye-Data\unspecified\jars\classes.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did several things and the error went away

1. deleted jar from lib folder in project
2. add to gradle

   dependencies {
              compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../libs')
              compile 'com.backendless:backendless:3.0.20.1'
          }
3. I noticed error about memory (To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
   It currently has approximately 910 MB.), so closed some other programs.

Answer (score -1):

If you add `com.backendless:backendless:3.0.20.1` dependency in your `build.gradle` file, then you don't need to also add `backendless.jar` into `libs` folder. I believe this was the reason you got a duplication error.

Comment: The error happened before backendless was added as a dependency, so that was not the cause.